# il2cpp compilation errors with Unity3d

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I am trying to compile my Unity3d C# scripts to run on arm64 devices for iOS.

The Unity build generates the xCode project with no problems but the xCode build produces some **Semantic Issue** errors:

```sh
CompileC /Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.o Classes/Native/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wno-trigraphs -fno-rtti -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -iquote /Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/myproject-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/myproject-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/myproject-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/myproject-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Classes -I/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode -I/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Classes/Native -I/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Libraries/bdwgc/include -I/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Libraries/libil2cpp/include -I/Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/../Assets/Plugins/myproject-iOS/.libs -mno-thumb -DINIT_SCRIPTING_BACKEND=1 -include /Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Prefix-ezhqqfjflyedusduqsaicoevmmnd/Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.dia -c /Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Classes/Native/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.cpp -o /Users/luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-eqdiboubmtwcvkcuyaficuwofpvl/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.o

/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Classes/Native/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.cpp:51:3: error: unknown type name 'AssemblyTitleAttribute_t500'; did you mean 'AssemblyTitleAttribute_t499'?
                AssemblyTitleAttribute_t500 * tmp;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                AssemblyTitleAttribute_t499
In file included from /Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Classes/Native/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.cpp:8:
/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Classes/Native/mscorlib_System_Reflection_AssemblyTitleAttributeMethodDeclarations.h:8:8: note: 'AssemblyTitleAttribute_t499' declared here
struct AssemblyTitleAttribute_t499;
       ^
/Users/luis/Projects/Unity/myproject-unity/Unity/myproject_xcode/Classes/Native/AssemblyAttributes_g_Mono_Posix_Assembly.cpp:52:10: error: unknown type name 'AssemblyTitleAttribute_t500'; did you mean 'AssemblyTitleAttribute_t499'?
                tmp = (AssemblyTitleAttribute_t500 *)il2cpp_codegen_object_new (&AssemblyTitleAttribute_t500_il2cpp_TypeInfo);
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       AssemblyTitleAttribute_t499
.....
                ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

<s>It happened when I started using the **micro msclib** and using the link.xml file as suggested here (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html) did not help. Also, I don't know what do I have to put in the link.xml file in my case.</s>

EDIT: I just found out this happens because I set the compatibility level to **.net 2.0 subset**. Still I don't know what classes I am using that cause this error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question, but I suggest you to look or post [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/ios-development.27/). Just too specific.

Comment: Even though this is working with the .NET 2.0 Subset profile, IL2CPP should not generate C++ code that won't compile in any cases. Can you submit a bug report for this issue via the Unity editor?